# Child element's box-shadow superior to parent's?

Tags: html, css, parent-child, box-shadow

Somehow I find this wierd and I couldn't solve it myself.

I have form with large outset `box-shadow` which overlaps top inner (inset) `box-shadow` of the parent container. I need to have parent's black inset shadow to be visible.

See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccspw1dh/)**

`z-index` does nothing.

My CSS:

```
#description {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 17px 11px -15px #000;
    padding-top: 10px!important;
    }
.upload {
    float: left;
    width: 696px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #546E7A;
    font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px -17px 0px 20px #546E7A;
    }
```

How come the child's prior?

Comment: Do you need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ccspw1dh/1/)?

Comment: I need parent's black inset `box-shadow` to be visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make the parent `shadow` visible as `shadow` is for the same `element` so the `z-index` will not work, but you can use `:pseudo` and add a `shadow` to it

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ccspw1dh/3/

```
#description:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 17px 11px -15px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

z-index will not help because .upload is a child of #description and its display will always have more priority than #description.

It is like creating a div with background black inside a div with background white. All you will see is black. Your box-shadow on the parent is still there but the drawing of the child shadow just totally covers it.

To solve your problem and still see the glow you could just make it smaller in .upload:

```
box-shadow: 0px -17px 0px 1px #546E7A;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccspw1dh/2/

Furthermore you can chain box-shadows like here:

```
box-shadow: 0px -17px 0px 1px #546E7A, inset 0px 17px 11px -15px #000;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccspw1dh/4/